# Implicit conversion not allowed on return

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, implicit-conversion

```
#include <optional>

bool f() {
  std::optional<int> opt;
  return opt;
}
```

Does not compile: `'return': cannot convert from 'std::optional<int>' to 'bool'`

Consulting reference I would have thought to find an explanation, but I read it as it should be ok.

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type
>   T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some
>   other type T2; in particular:
>
> - when the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with T2 as parameter;
> - when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that    expects T2;
> - **when initializing a new object of type T2, including return statement    in a function returning T2;**
> - when the expression is used in a switch statement (T2 is integral    type);
> - when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (T2 is    bool).

Comment: *"**Implicit** conversions are performed"*, but [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) of `std::optional` is **`explicit`**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`std::optional` doesn't have any facility for implicitly converting to `bool`. (Allowing implicit conversions to `bool` is generally considered a bad idea, since `bool` is an integral type so something like `int i = opt` would compile and do completely the wrong thing.)

`std::optional` *does* have a "contextual conversion" to bool, the definition of  which looks similar to a cast operator: `explicit operator bool()`. This cannot be used for implicit conversions; it only applies in certain specific situations where the expected "context" is a boolean one, like the condition of an if-statement.

What you want is `opt.has_value()`.

Answer (score 5):

From C++ [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

> When an object of type *optional< T >* is **contextually converted** to bool,
>   the conversion returns true if the object contains a value and false
>   if it does not contain a value.

Read about contextual conversions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> In the following contexts, the type bool is expected and the implicit
>   conversion is performed if the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed
>   (that is, an explicit conversion function such as explicit T::operator
>   bool() const; is considered). Such expression e is said to be
>   contextually converted to bool.
>
> - the controlling expression of if, while, for;
> - the operands of the built-in logical operators !, && and ||;
> - the first operand of the conditional operator ?:;
> - the predicate in a static_assert declaration;
> - the expression in a noexcept specifier;
> - the expression in an explicit specifier;

You can do the following hack:

```cpp
bool f() {
    std::optional<int> opt;
    return opt || false;
}
```

because contextual conversion happens in case of the built-in logical operators, but contextual conversion does **not** include `return` statements and `std::optional` by itself does **not** have implicit conversion to `bool`.

Therefore, it would be the best to use the [`std::optional<T>::has_value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool):

```cpp
bool f() {
    std::optional<int> opt;
    return opt.has_value();
}
```

Comment: what about `return {opt}` ? or `return bool{opt};`

Comment: @darune `return {opt};` won't work but `return static_cast<bool>(opt);` or `return bool{opt};` would work. However, it is suggested to use `has_value` member function because it really shows clear intention of what you want to do

Comment: Or the famous `return !!pot;` hack (`has_value` is better)

Answer (score 1):

That's because implicit coversion of std::optional to bool is not supported: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool

> constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept;

You have to explicitly convert to bool as `bool(opt)` or simply use `opt.has_value()` instead.

Comment: bool{opt} works as well and should be preferred over bool(opt)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really about implicit conversion, this is about the type of initialization.

What optional has is an explicit conversion function, i.e.

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

From N4849 [class.conv.fct]/p2

> A conversion function may be explicit (9.2.2), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion
>   for direct-initialization.

The above means that these cases will use the conversion function :
[dcl.init]/p16

> The initialization that occurs
>     (16.1) — for an initializer that is a parenthesized expression-list    or a braced-init-list,
>     (16.2) — for a new-initializer (7.6.2.7),
>     (16.3) — in a static_cast expression (7.6.1.8),
>     (16.4) — in a functional notation type conversion (7.6.1.3), and
>     (16.5) — in the braced-init-list form of a condition is called direct-initialization.

However, these cases will not use the conversion function :
[dcl.init]/p15

> The initialization that occurs in the = form of a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer or condition (8.5), as well as in argument
>   passing, function return, throwing an exception (14.2), handling an
>   exception (14.4), and member initialization (9.4.1), is called
>   copy-initialization.

The example in the question falls under the copy initialization case and does not use optional's conversion function.